# XSLT Sort and Remove duplicates based on element and attribute

Tags: xslt

Will you please help me out with my XSLT where I am struck,

**Requirement:** In my XML Records any of offer/sku is equal and offer/customer-attributes/custom-attribute/Feed_SKU is grater then I have to keep that record (Which means this is latest record and ignore the other one).

My case Feed_SKU = 09/07/2014 23:21:20 is latest record.

I have tried with xsl:key compare and having some hard time to parse attribute value (Feed_SKU). Could you please help me out here.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<enfinity xmlns="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/xcs/impex" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/xcs/impex catalog.xsd  http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt dt.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" family="enfinity" major="6" minor="1">
<offer import-mode="UPDATE" sku="36-5149574">
<sku>36-5149574</sku>
<custom-attributes>
<custom-attribute name="OriginalFileName" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">Message_20140709_2321130190_BP71794596.dat_SKU</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="FacilityId" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">385</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="GII" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">6661116</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="CountryOrigin" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">US</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="UOMSystem" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">I</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="CartonType" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">AF</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Catalog" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">36</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Height" dt:dt="quantity" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">3 in</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Length" dt:dt="quantity" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">14 in</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Width" dt:dt="quantity" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">10.5 in</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Weight" dt:dt="quantity" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">9.7 lb</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Feed_SKU" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">09/07/2014 23:21:14</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
</offer>
<offer import-mode="UPDATE" sku="36-5149574">
<sku>36-5149574</sku>
<custom-attributes>
<custom-attribute name="OriginalFileName" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">Message_20140709_2321130190_BP71794596.dat_SKU</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="FacilityId" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">385</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="GII" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">6661116</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="CountryOrigin" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">US</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="UOMSystem" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">I</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="CartonType" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">AF</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Catalog" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">36</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Height" dt:dt="quantity" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">3 in</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Length" dt:dt="quantity" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">14 in</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Width" dt:dt="quantity" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">10.5 in</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Weight" dt:dt="quantity" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">9.7 lb</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="Feed_SKU" dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">09/07/2014 23:23:23</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
</offer>
</enfinity>
```

XLST I am working on: (Not working)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                         version="1.0" 
                         xmlns:impex="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/xcs/impex" 
                         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/xcs/impex catalog.xsd  http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt dt.xsd" 
                         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <!-- key for grouping -->
    <xsl:key name="offerBySku" match="impex:offer" use="impex:sku"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- transfer attributes of the document element -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <!-- Muenchian method to get one iteration per sku -->
            <xsl:for-each select="impex:offer[generate-id() = generate-id(key('offerBySku', impex:sku)[1])]">
                <!-- sort the group by descending timestamp -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('offerBySku', impex:sku)">
                    <!-- rearrange the timestamp to year, month, day, time -->
                    <xsl:sort order="descending" select="concat(
                          substring(impex:custom-attributes/impex:custom-attribute[@name='Feed_SKU'], 7, 4),
                          substring(impex:custom-attributes/impex:custom-attribute[@name='Feed_SKU'], 4, 2),
                          substring(impex:custom-attributes/impex:custom-attribute[@name='Feed_SKU'], 1, 2),
                          substring(impex:custom-attributes/impex:custom-attribute[@name='Feed_SKU'], 11))"/>
                    <!-- copy just the first element in sorted order, i.e. the one with the latest date-->
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 - It's my limitation. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you start by doing the required reading: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html Then, if you have a specific difficulty in implementing this, edit your question.

Comment: I am trying with the xslt attached above but no luck. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this problem, first grouping together the offers that share the same `sku` and second finding the latest date within each group.  For the first part you can use Muenchian grouping, for the second you need to get creative with string manipulation - XSLT 1.0 doesn't have any special support for dates and times so you need to massage the timestamp values into a form where chronological ordering matches lexicographic ordering.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
        xmlns:impex="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/xcs/impex">

  <!-- key for grouping -->
  <xsl:key name="offerBySku" match="impex:offer" use="impex:sku" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- transfer attributes of the document element -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <!-- Muenchian method to get one iteration per sku -->
      <xsl:for-each select="impex:offer[
           generate-id() = generate-id(key('offerBySku', impex:sku)[1])]">
        <!-- sort the group by descending timestamp -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('offerBySku', impex:sku)">
          <!-- rearrange the timestamp to year, month, day, time -->
          <xsl:sort order="descending" select="concat(
              substring(impex:custom-attributes/impex:custom-attribute[
                          @name='Feed_SKU'], 7, 4),
              substring(impex:custom-attributes/impex:custom-attribute[
                          @name='Feed_SKU'], 4, 2),
              substring(impex:custom-attributes/impex:custom-attribute[
                          @name='Feed_SKU'], 1, 2),
              substring(impex:custom-attributes/impex:custom-attribute[
                          @name='Feed_SKU'], 11))" />
          <!-- copy just the first element in sorted order, i.e. the one with
               the latest date -->
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I've assumed the timestamps are dd/mm/yyyy since the 7th of September 2014 would be after the date when this question was asked, but if they're actually mm/dd/yyyy then you'll have to swap the second and third `substring` calls to get the right ordering.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian. It's perfectly working. When I implement this with different data I am experiencing issue with namespaces. my root element Store has some namespaces something like xmlns, xsi:schemaLocation, xmlns:xsi and someother stuff. I just wanted to copy as is to my output. If I remove them xslt is working perfectly. Is there anyway we can mute this validations and copy the line as is to output?

Comment: @Developer there are many other questions you can find on Stack Overflow that discuss dealing with namespaces in XSLT - essentially if the source document has `xmlns="xxxx"` then you need to bind the same namespace URI to a prefix in the stylesheet (add `xmlns:ns0="xxxx"` to the `xsl:stylesheet`) and use that prefix consistently in your XPath expressions and match patterns (e.g. `<xsl:key match="ns0:offer" use="ns0:sku"/>`)

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a line that will copy the attributes of the document element, since you say you want to preserve the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute as well as the namespace declarations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian. I have attached my original xml using that I am running the xslt. It is only printing the header line and it is not taking offer element. When I remove xmlns="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/xcs/impex" from header it works perfectly. Will you please guide me.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Haley. Was trying to figure out but no luck so far..appreciate any help.

Comment: @Ian Roberts I followed your suggetion and added namespace under stylesheet and refering all my elements with namespace name. The PROBLEM is the result it is producing is not right. But it is printing namespaces perfectly. I am struck and any help greatly appriciated. Thank you. Updated my input xml and my xslt for refrence.

Comment: @Developer you missed one - `impex:custom-attributes/custom-attribute` needs to be `impex:custom-attributes/impex:custom-attribute`

Comment: Thank you @IanRoberts. My bad fixed it. When I run I see it is generating duplicate data. Not sure what is going on. Will you please help me out here...

Comment: @Developer - You have 2 `<xsl:copy-of select="." />` in your XSLT. Ian Roberts' XSLT only has 1 (in the `xsl:if`).